# How to save image to the build folder?

Tags: java, spring, image, file-upload

A friend of mine told me that I mustnt save files in the directory of the project, but to the build directory, but couldn't help me to do so

I tried to search a way to get the path to the directory, but couldn't find a way, that doent require hardcoding the path

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.